# Converting Tab Delimited txt to JSON

Tags: json, csv, type-conversion

I have a 1.9GB tab delimited file that is in the form of an xlsx file. I could write a script to convert it to CSV and then convert THAT to json, but I'm just curious if there is a more direct way to do this. Thanks! :)

Comment: [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) can convert tsv to json directly.  For a more precise answer, a description of the expected output and a sample of the data would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is an option, but you can import it into some database (for example mongo) and then export relatively easily with that

Answer (score 0):

I came accross a similar problem recently, and what I found really easy to do was actually go directly from XLSX to JSON using MATLAB.

IMPORTING XLSX: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html

EXPORTING JSON: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/jsonencode.html

It might take a little bit of time for such a large file, but I did it on a file about 400MB in size with no problem.